During starting InnoDB, error log shows 'Could not open log file.'
2024-04-11T05:07:26.565563Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-04-11T05:07:26.742860Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.3.0) starting as process 5688
2024-04-11T05:07:26.753065Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-04-11T05:07:26.798749Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-04-11T05:20:55.418230Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysqld: File '',/'5+%?ͪ1,)%9?ͫ33335?ͬ7%(+1?ͭ9)3&-?ͮ-$/'5+?ͯ%71,)?Ͱ'''''?ͱ(+/7%?Ͳ)3&,9?ͳ+$/'5?ʹ,)%73?͵----/?Ͷ/7%(,?ͷ3&,9*?͸5+$/(?͹71,)&?ͺ/?ͻ%(+/7?ͼ'5+$/?ͽ)%71,?;*****?Ϳ+/7%(???,9)3'???/'5+%???1,)%9???33335???7%(+1???9)3&-???1$/'5+???%71,)???'''''???(+/7%???)3&,9???+$/'5???,)%73???----/???/7%(,???3&,9*???5+$/(???71,)&???3???%(+/7???&,9)3???'5+$/???)%71,???*****???+/7%(???,9)3'???/'5+%???1,)%9???
2024-04-11T05:21:30.235988Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010958] [Server] Could not open log file.
2024-04-11T05:21:30.236004Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010041] [Server] Can't init tc log
2024-04-11T05:21:30.236011Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-04-11T05:21:30.874313Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.3.0)  Homebrew.
2024-04-11T05:21:30.874324Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.


it is missing a read write permission for the log file directory. see https://serverfault.com/questions/42531/where-is-my-mysql-log-on-os-x

Check does my.ini is not damaged...

Please post your complete TEXT of your my.ini so we can see your requests for startup.

@WilsonHauck This is the setting. Homebrew MySQL server config [mysqld] # Only allow connections from localhost bind-address = 127.0.0.1 mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
